# I am new to Factory girl usage in cucumber with watir

Tags: cucumber, factory-bot, watir-webdriver

I have the following step definition:

```
And(/^I enter my credentials and submit$/) do
  on(LoginPage) do |page|
    page.login_with($test_user['email_address'], $test_user['password'])
    page.click_login_button
  end
end
```

And my factory girl

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.eamail 'radhasel9@gmail.com'
  u.password  '123456'
  u.admin true
end
```

So how could I pass this factory girl data into the step definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory Girl is a tool designed to mimic active record to test your models, it doesn't just magically hook up and create step definitions for you. If you want to *use* factory girl within your step definitions, you need to include it in your cucumber [env.rb file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

```
World FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

Then you can simply make whatever step definitions you'd like using factory girl. [Here is another link that may help you](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory-girl-step-definitions-for-cucumber).